# how to set max_depth in sklearn implementation of Isolation Forest?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, isolation-forest

I was using `sklearn`'s Isolation Forest and using that to predict on other samples (drawn from the same population). Due to the large size of the samples, I cannot fit the Forest on the whole data (because I cannot convert that data into pandas dataframe), hence this approach.

As it was taking time, I was thinking about reducing the maximum depth of the trees. According to [`sklearn`'s documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html), "

> *The maximum depth of each tree is set to ceil(log_2(n)) where  is the number of samples used to build the tree (see (Liu et al., 2008) for
> more details)*

"

But as I want only the topmost anomalies, I think I can limit the depth of the trees to something even less than ceil(log_2(n)). And I think that might reduce the time taken to fit and make predictions using that model. But `sklearn` does not support the parameter `max_depth`. Is there a way to specify the `max_depth` in `sklearn`

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py#L277) line in the source code.

Comment: why don't you just set `max_samples` ? That is to sample some amount of your data to construct each base estimator

Comment: @StupidWolf I am afraid reducing `max_samples` would make the iForest think some normal points as anomalous.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thanks. Just not sure if changing that line would affect the overall computation (i.e. if I need to adjust some other lines of the code as well)